# javascript How to read and higlight word by word

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an html like this

```
<ul>
<li>This is text</li>
</ul>
<p> bbbb ccc</p>
<p> <b> bbbb ccc</b></p>
```

I have all words index so i want to higligh each text against its index so is it possible that i turn it into this form(assign id to first parent):

```
<ul>
<li id="0">This is text</li>
</ul>
<p id="12"> bbbb ccc<p/>
<p> <b id="22"> bbbb ccc</b><p/>
```

**id** represent the first index of word.

I was trying below solution which is only applicable for case in which only text would contain in **p** tags and its working fine there. 
But problem is when we have other tags comes in our html.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var allP = $("#inputText").find("p");
  var indexCount = 0;
  $.each(allP, function(key, value) {
    var paraText = $(value).text().trim();
    var textCount = paraText.length;
    if (textCount > 0) {
      $("#inputText p").eq(key).addClass('' + indexCount);
      indexArray.push(indexCount);
    }
    indexCount += textCount;
  });
});

function changeColor(index, word) {
  var alreadyTxt = $('.highlightClass').text();
  $('.highlightClass').replaceWith(alreadyTxt);
  var paraVal = getIndexVal(index);
  if (paraVal != -1) {
    var txt = $('.' + paraVal).text();
    var filteredText = txt.substr(0, index - paraVal) + '<span    class="highlightClass">' + word + '</span>' + txt.substr(index - paraVal + word.length);
    $('.' + paraVal).html(filteredText)
  }
}

function getIndexVal(ind) {
  var retunValue = -1;
  var lastIndex = 0;
  $.each(indexArray, function(key, value) {
    if (ind <= value) {
      retunValue = lastIndex;
      return false;
    }
    lastIndex = value;
  });
  return retunValue;
}
```

If there is any other better solution please suggest me, Thanks

Comment: can you add example that shows result you want to achieve?

Comment: Not clear what's your problem! explain more please!

Comment: update please have a look now :)

Comment: The way you close your `p` tag is really amusing!! Please change it to `<p></p>`

Comment: @ThomasSebastian it must be a combo of `<p>` and `<br/>` from HTML6? 0_-

Comment: @ThomasSebastian that's not the problem :)

Comment: what are those 0, 12 and 22 - how are they calculated?

Comment: what is `words index`?

Comment: first character index of a word.

Comment: like?... `bbbb` is a word. first character `b` located at first position. so `bbbb ccc` should be `11`, not a `22`

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var id_array =[];

  $('[id]').each(function() { 
    id_array.push(parseInt($(this).attr("id"))); 
    console.log(parseInt($(this).attr("id")));
  });

  // Sort ID 
  id_array.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});

  // highlight each ID by serialy 
  for (i = 0; i < id_array.length; i++) {
    // highlight or change background of each id
    $("#"+id_array[i]).css("background-color", "yellow");    
    // You can define delay option here to sea effect
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li id="0">This is text</li>
</ul>
<p id="12"> bbbb ccc<p/>
<p> <b id="22"> bbbb ccc</b><p/>
<p> <b id="2"> 22222</b><p/>
```